# Finding where a variable has a decimal

Tags: php

```
$dec = is_float($spaces);
if ($dec === true){
   echo "Error"
 }
```

Why can't I get my if statement to check whether there is a decimal present once I decode it from JSON to a php variable.
I tried that above and is_float, strpos and strstr. Hope you can help. Thanks

Comment: Do a `print_r()` of your decoded json and edit it in your answer.

Comment: Better if you use var_dump(), but in general is_float() tests the PHP internal type, which it might not be what you want. Also a sample input JSON would be nice

Comment: You are right sir. After 8 years i still mix them up :)

Comment: {"timestamp": "22:39:48", "carpark_name": "creche", "spaces_available": 28.57319771804829}

Comment: Array ( [timestamp] => 22:40:38 [carpark_name] => creche [spaces_available] => 93.453051899528 )

Comment: So what do you suggest me to do for the if statement to work?